# How to plot a barplot with color based on a categorical variable

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a horizontal bar plot showing the number of views of 50 YouTube channels with seaborn. However, I can't manage to color the bar based on the category "category" of the DataFrame without the bar being very thin due to the plot keeping space for every other category (but they are all set to 0)

The DataFrame:

[image: Dataframe]

Maybe using hue isn't the way to go, but i haven't found other way that are close to what i want

Here is what i tried:

The code below:

```
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 16))

sns.barplot(x="30d_average_views", y="display_name", data=df_name_to_views[0:20],
            hue='category',hue_order=['musique', 'divertissement', 'humour'],
            )
```

The result

[image: Initial plot]

This is nearly what I want, but the bar are so thin it is very hard to read, and it will be worse as I add more data and more category.

Comment: You can use `sns.barplot(..., dodge=False)` if the display names are unique.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to swap the y and hue group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i can't mark @JohanC's answer as accepted, i will just copy and paste it here:

You can use

```
sns.barplot(..., dodge=False)
```

if the display names are unique

Here is my final graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPvlp.png

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the ["categroy", "display_name"] bins don't have enough data in them?

For example,
if you do barplot to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 1, 3],
    'cat': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'cat2': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
})

seaborn.barplot(x='x', y='cat', hue='cat2', data=df)
```

it  will show 2 cat2 bars for 'a' and only 1 for 'd'.

If I add however 1 more data point to ['b', 'd'] bin, both 'a' and 'b' will have 2 bars.

It appears that in your graph, all "category" variable are present, it's just "display_name" doesn't have enough data for all of them.

What happens if you run `df.groupby(["display_name", "category"]).count()`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
However i can't use barplot since i only have 1 value for each youtube channel

When i run df.groupby(["display_name", "category"]).count(), it only shows a list of every "display name" with a value of 1 in the category "30d_average_views" since they only have one value that count the whole number of views. I would like the exact same graph as i showed previously, but with bars that take the whole size